# Is there any method to access local files and my program is on server node.js?

Tags: node.js

When I am executing this code on my local system its working fine. but when I am executing this code on server. It's not working.

```
try {
    var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
        input: require('fs').createReadStream('C:/sync/test.txt')
    });

    lineReader.on('line', function (localDirectory) {
        console.log('Line from file:', localDirectory);
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Location `C:/sync/test.txt` is in your pc.

I suggest you to put file in your project, example:

```
/your-project
   /files
     test.txt
```

`index.js`:

```
try {
    var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
                                         // create file path using __dirname
        input: require('fs').createReadStream(__dirname + '/files/test.txt')
    });

    lineReader.on('line', function (localDirectory) {
        console.log('Line from file:', localDirectory);
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

Or use a [env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) variable to define file location for different enviroments:

`.env`:

```
FILE_PATH=/path/to/file
```

`index.js`:

```
require('dotenv').config()
try {
    var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
        input: require('fs').createReadStream(FILE_PATH)
    });

    lineReader.on('line', function (localDirectory) {
        console.log('Line from file:', localDirectory);
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

Comment: I can't keep 'text.txt' it in my server project, because its keep updating. I have to access with it using local pc. Is there any way? Thanks.

Comment: You need to create a server on your pc where you get access to the file and create a public url to you server. You can use https://ngrok.com/ to create public url. After it use second example in my answer